# link OpenGL to Qt Creator under Mac osx

Tags: macos, qt, opengl

I'm trying to link OpenGL to my Qt .pro file. I've installed the SDL Library properly and this is my .pro file :

```
QT += opengl
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/Headers
LIBS += -framework Cocoa -framework SDL
LIBS += -F/Library/Frameworks

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
           SDLMain.h

OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += \
          SDLMain.m
```

The problem is that `#include <GL/gl.h>` and `#include <GL/glu.h>` are still not find by the QtCreator. The error message is:

> /Users/Anass/testsdl/main.cpp:42: erreur : 'GL/glu.h' file not found

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you share the error message? It's unclear to me what you mean by "#include and #include are still not find".

Comment: sorry, i wanted to say that when i put :
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

the error message is : /Users/Anass/testsdl/main.cpp:42: erreur : 'GL/glu.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not the correct header file names on Mac OS:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

On Mac OS, for headers that are part of a framework, the first part of the include file name is the name of the framework. This is `OpenGL` in this case. Therefore, the include statements need to be:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

Also make sure that you link the OpenGL framework by adding `-framework OpenGL` to the link options.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to add the OpenGL framework as well if you want to use OpenGL.

Comment: i added it, look at my .pro file : QT += opengl

Comment: @Anouss: That just adds the QtOpenGL module, not the MacOS-X OpenGL framework, which is a separate thing.